# Facebook Graph API to get public video Info

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was using simple HTTP Get call like the code below to get PUBLIC video information from facebook. The user enter a video url and with this code I got video information:

```
var request=$.ajax({
            url:'http://graph.facebook.com/'+id + '?fields=format,source,title',                
            timeout:5000,
            success:function(data){         

                // do some stuff with data

            },
            error:function(){
                displayError('facebook');   
            }
        });
```

The code was working fine but recently this starts to return an error

```
error: {
  message: "An access token is required to request this resource.",
  type: "OAuthException",
  code: 104,
  fbtrace_id: "HYdRovB1cyn"
}
```

It seems that I have to pass AccessToken in some way to the API but, the question is how/where should I get this token while I do not want the user login into facebook, cause I just simply need some info of a public video.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must send a token in your request. You will get the token when you create a Facebook Application, there is a guide in this blog: http://mattpilz.com/facebook-graph-access-token-photo-album/

Comment: Thanks but it seems the blog is not updated. I follow the instruction to get access_tokon and when I browse the URL which contain App_id and App_Secret, I receive the same error that access_token is requierd.

Comment: Well, I found the solution. I got a temp access_token from Graph API Explorer, add it to the end of instruction of this blog, and took the permanent token_id. Thanks.

Comment: @Mazdak you should not expose your own, long-lived token in client-side code. You _need to_ either make the user login to your app, so that you can use their access token to fetch this data - or you need to do it server-side, so that your access token will be kept secret.